# null video when creating a thumbnail in kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, thumbnails

I've been looking around for a couple of days already, but I can't find a solution to my problem.

Device fisical and virtual: API 29
Problem: I'm trying to create and view a thumbnail of a movie I have in internal storage, i get this error:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: video must not be null
W/System.err:     at com.checkme.newmobile.ui.reports.updateRvAdapter.onBindViewHolder(updateRvAdapter.kt:151)
W/System.err:     at com.checkme.newmobile.ui.reports.updateRvAdapter.onBindViewHolder(updateRvAdapter.kt:24)
W/System.err:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7254)
W/System.err:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7337)
W/System.err:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6194)
W/System.err:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6460)
W/System.err:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
W/System.err:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
W/System.err:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
...
```

path in local storage: /data/user/0/project_name/files/file_name.mp4

```
try {
    val fileName = phaseMediaList[i].localPath.split("/")
    val f = File(context?.filesDir, fileName[fileName.size-1])
    val video = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(FileInputStream(f))
    if (video != null) {hasVideo = true}
    ...
} catch (e: Throwable) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

The error in this line of code is raised:

```
val video = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(FileInputStream(f))
```

Printing on the screen its content is null.

The content of this:

```
val f = File(context?.filesDir, fileName[fileName.size-1])
```

it's correct: /data/user/0/project_name/files/file_name.mp4

Unfortunately, on the web I find only quite outdated solutions, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: BitmapFactory can generate bitmaps from image files but not from video files.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I recently changed my logic, moving the images from an internal database (SQLite, blob field) to the phone storage, for the movies I used this method BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(...) and it worked, but now in that database cell I have only the reference to the path of the object. what should i use?

Comment: So you are saying that BitmapFactory can generate bitmaps from a video file in a byte array. I have difficulty to believe that.

Comment: your behavior does not help with my question